# mysql_num_rows giving error on output of number of rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a warning that `mysql_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be resource. this is my code for getting the number of post and then printing the number of rows.

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM amityusers WHERE added_by='$user'");            

    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $hoot = $array['post'];
        $num_hoot = mysql_num_rows($hoot);
    }
?>
```

How can I print the number of rows and what is the problem?

Comment: `echo $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);` before of your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets convert your MySQL to MySQLi. Put outside the loop your mysqli_num_rows. **AND** replace the variable inside your `mysqli_num_rows()` to *$result* instead of *$hoot*. And don't forget *echo*:

```
<?php

$yourConnection=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","yourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($yourConnection,"SELECT * FROM amityusers WHERE added_by='$user'");
while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$hoot = $array['post'];
}
$num_hoot = mysqli_num_rows($result); /* PUT THIS OUTSIDE YOUR LOOP AND PUT $result INSTEAD OF $hoot VARIABLE*/

echo "Total result of ".$num_hoot;

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just take out the `mysql_num_rows()` outside the loop, and change the variable to `$result`

```
$num_hoot = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you can use `count()` to get the no of post

```
while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $hoot = $array['post'];
   echo $num_hoot = count($hoot); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$result` in `mysql_num_rows`

```
$num_hoot = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

first,do not use deprecated mysql functions

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM amityusers WHERE added_by='$user'") or die(mysql_error());   
$num_hoot = mysql_num_rows($result);         
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$post= $array['post'];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on this way

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");  
$selectdb = mysql_select_db("mydbname",$con);  
$result = mysql_query("select * from student");  
$number_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);  
echo "Number of rows fetched are : ". $number_of_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it work for you

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM amityusers WHERE added_by='$user'") or die(mysql_error());   
    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result); 

    $post = array();

    if($num_row > 1)
    {        
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $post[]= $array['post'];   
    }
    var_dump($post);
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'no row found';
    }
```